# Copy file from Master to slave

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

This is my first post about Jenkins I know very little about the product, but want to copy a file from the master to a slave,

there is a batch file that runs the following:

> cd \Program Files(x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TestTrackingPlatform\Platform_ML1x\ %systemroot%\System32\xcopy ML10_V_3.54.3B7_7180.bin /Y \mcs600\c$\Jenkins\workspace\FleetFunctionalTestSetup1

so the batch file should copy the bin file from the folder `platform_ML1x\` to the slave MCS600 and place it the following location `Jenkins\workspace\FleetFunctionalTestSetup1`

The batch file is located on the master and then via the web GUI 
under the build firmware run the job and the console output shows the following

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TestTrackingPlatform\Platform_ML1x>C:\WINDOWS\System32\xcopy "ML10_V_3.54.3B7_7180.bin\" x:\mcs600\w$\Jenkins\workspace\FleetFunctionalTestSetup1 /Y 
>   Invalid drive specification

I can see that there was a plugin Copy To Slave Plugin  but its been suspended due to unresolved security vulnerabilities

Any help gratefully received 
Phils